# Decoding UTF-8 std::string to std::u32string?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++17

Is there a way in C++17, with the C++17 standard library, to efficiently decode a std::string that contains a valid sequence of UTF-8 code units into a std::u32string that contains the corresponding sequence of code points (UTF-32 code units)? ie such that they both represent the same text?

Put another way, how do I implement the following function:

```
std::u32string decode_utf8(const std::string& utf8_string) {
    ???
}
```

For context, here is my current solution:

```
inline std::u32string decode_utf8(const std::string& utf8_string) {
  std::u32string result;
  result.resize(utf8_string.size());
  size_t output_pos = 0;

  const char* next_code_unit_ptr = &utf8_string[0];

  auto get_next_code_unit = [&] { return uint8_t(*next_code_unit_ptr++); };

  auto mask_match = [](uint8_t code_unit, uint8_t mask, uint8_t value) {
    return ((code_unit & mask) == value);
  };

  auto write_code_point = [&](uint32_t code_point) {
    result[output_pos] = char32_t(code_point);
    output_pos++;
  };

  while (true) {
    uint8_t starting_code_unit = get_next_code_unit();

    if (mask_match(starting_code_unit, 0b1000'0000, 0b0000'0000)) {
      if (starting_code_unit == 0) break;
      write_code_point(starting_code_unit);
      continue;
    }

    uint32_t code_point = 0;

    auto accumulate_trailing_code_unit = [&] {
      uint8_t trailing_code_unit = get_next_code_unit();
      if (!mask_match(trailing_code_unit, 0b1100'0000, 0b1000'0000))
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid UTF-8");
      code_point <<= 6;
      code_point |= (trailing_code_unit & 0b0011'1111);
    };

    if (mask_match(starting_code_unit, 0b1110'0000, 0b1100'0000)) {
      code_point = (starting_code_unit & 0b0001'1111);
      accumulate_trailing_code_unit();
      write_code_point(code_point);
    } else if (mask_match(starting_code_unit, 0b1111'0000, 0b1110'0000)) {
      code_point = (starting_code_unit & 0b0000'1111);
      accumulate_trailing_code_unit();
      accumulate_trailing_code_unit();
      write_code_point(code_point);
    } else if (mask_match(starting_code_unit, 0b1111'1000, 0b1111'0000)) {
      code_point = (starting_code_unit & 0b0000'0111);
      accumulate_trailing_code_unit();
      accumulate_trailing_code_unit();
      accumulate_trailing_code_unit();
      write_code_point(code_point);
    } else
      throw std::runtime_error("Invalid UTF-8");
  };

  result.resize(output_pos);

  return result;
}
```

Is there an easier or quicker way?

Comment: That's a YesNoMaybe - you had to ask? That's the job of [codecvt_utf8](https://codingtidbit.com/2020/02/09/c17-codecvt_utf8-is-deprecated/) which was [deprecated in C++ 17 without an alternative](https://codingtidbit.com/2020/02/09/c17-codecvt_utf8-is-deprecated/) .You could use [codecvt<char32_t, char, mbstate_t>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) but that gets deprecated in C++ 20, which brings support for real UTF8 strings with `char8_t` and `u8string`. But no UTF8 streams

Comment: I think we can safely say that Unicode is the Vietnam of C++.

Comment: For reference (not a solution) check [outputting char8_t const* to cout and wcout, one compiles one not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613226/outputting-char8-t-const-to-cout-and-wcout-one-compiles-one-not). [Tom Honermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11634221/tom-honermann) is the author of several of those proposals and answers similar questions all the time. Perhaps one of his answers will help

Comment: UTF-8 is very easy to decode to UTF-32 manually. You don't need library support for it. It takes only a handful of lines of code to accomplish. There are several questions on StackOverflow on this very topic.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If it was that easy it wouldn't take the C++ working group so long to get it right. Big-endian or little-endian? How do you make this fast? How will your conversion code work with all the other functions and libraries that need it? This is a job for the standard library of any language, not individual programmers. It's better to use a deprecated class while waiting for a replacement than rolling one's own

Comment: Regardless of whether this is easy or hard to implement, I think if the standard library provides unicode strings it should also provide a function to convert between them.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos it provides *some* Unicode strings and conversions. One of the big problems, especially around UTF8, is that everything has to be rewritten to differentiate between `char` and `char8_t` now. Until C++20, the language and OSs like Linux effectively *ignored* UTF8 as a distinct type and just treaded single-byte strings as whatever the locale said they were. This may be good for a server, very bad for a desktop user having to work with different codepages, or local + UTF8 files

Comment: @AndrewTomazos I've encountered several questions from R users whose C++ packages used `string` everywhere. That failed spectacularly as eg French data scientists started processing Polish or Russian data files (never mind Chinese).

Comment: @AndrewTomazos, it was pointed out to me on the [SG16 Slack channel](https://cpplang.slack.com/messages/sg16_unicode) that there are two potential security issues with the implementation of `decode_utf8` that you provided.  1) It stops at the first NUL code unit, so does not necessarily convert the entire input string, and 2) it doesn't detect [overlong sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings) such as `0xC0 0x80` (an overlong encoding of NUL).

Answer (score 2):

The requested `decode_utf8` function can be implemented in C++17 using deprecated standard facilities.  However, the use of a `std::codecvt` facet and its virtual interfaces will limit efficiency.

The following example uses the deprecated `std::wstring_convert` class, but avoids use of the deprecated `codecvt_utf8` facet.

```
#include <locale>
#include <cassert>

std::u32string decode_utf8(const std::string& utf8_string) {
  struct destructible_codecvt : public std::codecvt<char32_t, char, std::mbstate_t> {
    using std::codecvt<char32_t, char, std::mbstate_t>::codecvt;
    ~destructible_codecvt() = default;
  };
  std::wstring_convert<destructible_codecvt, char32_t> utf32_converter;
  return utf32_converter.from_bytes(utf8_string);
}

int main() {
  bool cmp = std::u32string(U"\U0001F64A") == decode_utf8(u8"\U0001F64A");
  assert(cmp);
  return !cmp;
}
```

The above code will *not* compile in C++20 since `u8""` string literals are of type `const char8_t[]`; that issue can be mitigated to some degree using the techniques discussed and implemented at https://github.com/tahonermann/char8_t-remediation.  Changing the uses of `std::string` to `std::u8string` and `char` to `char8_t` will not suffice to make it work in C++20 because `std::wstring_convert` only works with `char`-based types; a (user provided) replacement for `std::wstring_convert` is required to port the above code to C++20.

C++20 does not provide efficient means to perform the requested conversions.  This is a problem that [SG16](https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16) is well aware of and is working on (see [P1629](https://wg21.link/p1629)).  Experimental implementations will be available in the C++23 time frame, but whether a solution will gain consensus and make it through the committee process in time to be adopted for C++23 is yet to be determined.